# Scale Image With JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code where I am trying to resize an image on hover, I think I need to add a class to it, but I have struggling on making it look smooth and actually working. So, can I just change class p-6 to p-5 to approach the effect i want?

This is the HTML markup related to the image:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
  <div class="p-5">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="img/joe.jpg" alt="Joe's Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using CSS animations, like this:

**Note:** I used an id below, but class would be the way to go if it's many pictures (and not only one) you want to do this to.

**Note 2:** Of course you can solve this with JavaScript and jQuery, if you want to do that instead, please let me know - and I'll update the answer.

```css
#my-image {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#my-image:hover {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
   <div class="p-5">
     <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle " src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/92/53/56/240_F_92535664_IvFsQeHjBzfE6sD4VHdO8u5OHUSc6yHF.jpg" alt="Example Image" id="my-image">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would perfer Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Using only **JQuery** you can use the [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) listener for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and manage the **CSS** properties also with JQuery using [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method. For scale an element you can use the CSS `transition` in conjunction with `transform: scale(<some_number>)` properties. Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".img-wrapper").find("img").css("transition", "transform 500ms ease-in-out");

    $(".img-wrapper").hover(    
        // Handler for mouseenter
        function()
        {
            $(this).find("img").css("transform", "scale(1.2)");
        },
        // Handler for mouseleave
        function()
        {
            $(this).find("img").css("transform", "scale(1)");
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
   <div class="img-wrapper p-5 text-center bg-info">
     <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="Joe's Image">
   </div>
</div>
```